# Django executable app built by PyInstaller on Ubuntu can't find static files

Tags: django, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have an following error in running executable app on Ubuntu 18.04 developed based Django-1.8 and converted by PyInstaller3.4.

```
TypeError at /static/css/style.css
expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/static/css/style.css
Django Version: 1.8
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
Exception Location: django/views/static.py in serve, line 54
Python Executable:  /home/ksi/Projects/abcalarm/dist/webapp/webapp
Python Version: 3.6.7
Python Path:    
['/home/ksi/Projects/abcalarm/dist/webapp/base_library.zip',
 '/home/ksi/Projects/abcalarm/dist/webapp']
Server time:    Fri, 1 Feb 2019 15:52:36 +0000

Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
                                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
django/views/static.py in serve
                fullpath = os.path.join(document_root, newpath) ...
▶ Local vars
```

When I run Django source in development environment It runs ok. But the converted app by PyInstaller is not finding static path.